# The action isn’t supported in Word Online

Tags: ms-word, office-js

When I try to start Add-In in the Word Online, it shows me the following:

```json
{
    "name": "OfficeExtension.Error",
    "code": "NotAllowed",
    "message": "The action isn’t supported in Word Online. Check the OfficeExtension.Error.debugInfo for more information.",
    "traceMessages ": [],
    "innerError ": null,
    "debugInfo ": {
        "code ": "NotAllowed ",
        "message ": "The action isn’t supported in Word Online. Check the OfficeExtension.Error.debugInfo for more information.",
        "errorLocation ": "Range.delete "
    }
}
```

Here is the code:

```js
Word.run(function (context) {

    // Getting current selection    
    var range = context.document.getSelection();
    range.delete();
    range.insertHtml(text, TEXT_REPLACE);

    return context.sync().then(function () {

    });

}).catch(function (error) {
    handleError(error);
});
```

According to [Office Add-In documentation](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/range) it should be supported by Word Online

Comment: Hi, anyone can help me?

Comment: Any comments on it? I don't know what to do. It just doesn't work. Range.delete and Range.insertHtml just don't work. Based on the official documentation it should be supported in Word API v1.1 (https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/range).

Here is the snippet from my manifest.xml: 

<Requirements>
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
  <Set Name="WordApi" MinVersion="1.1"/>
 </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is supported in Word Online. That said, make sure you're manifest specifies `ReadWriteDocument` for your add-in's [permissions](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/permissions).